# WSO2IS - deployment.toml - Invalid escape sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm facing some problems converting user-mgt.xml file from wso2is:5.8.0 to wso2is:5.10.0 version. I have some configurations in user-mgt.xml to primary user store using ldap and now when I use deployment.toml I can't start the server.

docker container log:

```
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,627] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\.' (line 44, column 53)
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,627] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\.' (line 45, column 59)
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,627] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\S' (line 47, column 24)
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,628] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\S' (line 48, column 30)
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,628] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\-' (line 50, column 34)
[2021-03-01 21:42:19,628] ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - Invalid escape sequence '\S' (line 51, column 30)
```

user-mgt.xml from old version 5.8.0

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">         
 <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$</Property>
 <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$</Property>
  <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
  <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
  <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
  <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
  <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
  <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

deployment.toml from newer version 5.10.0:

```
[user_store.properties]
...
UsernameJavaRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
UsernameJavaScriptRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg = "Username pattern policy violated"
PasswordJavaRegEx = "^[\S]{5,30}$"
PasswordJavaScriptRegEx = "^[\S]{5,30}$"
PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg = "Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters"
RolenameJavaRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$"
RolenameJavaScriptRegEx = "^[\S]{3,30}$"
....
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `\` in the configs, you need to use the escape character(`\`). (eg: `^[\\S]{5,30}$`)

Try out these.

```
[user_store]
username_java_regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
username_java_script_regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
username_java_regex_violation_error_msg = "Username pattern policy violated"
password_java_regex = "^[\\S]{5,30}$"
password_java_script_regex = "^[\\S]{5,30}$"
password_java_regrx_violation_error_msg = "Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters"
rolename_java_regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-|//]{3,30}$"
rolename_java_script_regex = "^[\\S]{3,30}$"
```